# Sharing Windows universal app with friends

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I developed a Windows 8.1 Universal app, I want to share it with my friends for testing. I don't want to share entire code, Is their a way to create a exe file and share with them ? I know in windows phone we can do that by sharing .XAP file. Looking for such option in windows desktop apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a .appx file.
To do that, right click on your project and select `Store -> "Create App packages..."`

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the Project and Select store->Create App Packages and follow on screen instructions. 
It will generate the required package files along with the certificate. Now go to the folder and edit the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 powershell script file. Replace the line

```
`$NeedDeveloperLicense = CheckIfNeedDeveloperLicense`
```

with

```
$NeedDeveloperLicense = $false
```

Now, if you run the powershell script you can install the Windows Store Application without any issues on any system.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is company app, I suggest you side load.
If your app that you want to give to your friends, I suggest you to using Promotional codes that you can found in Windows Dev center.